# String format with 3 conditions: is it possible?

Tags: java, string, format, output, conditional-operator

I want to format my output text so it's corresponding with my counter values. For an instance, I have 3 counters and would like to output different words when it is 1, 2 and more than 2.

I tried with String format, but it's only good for 2 different counters.

Here is my code:

```
package vaja13;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Vaja13
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.print("Vnesi besedilo: ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String besedilo = sc.nextLine();
        char [] tabela  = besedilo.toCharArray();
        int crke = 0,stevilke = 0,presledki  = 0;
        int i=0;
        while(i<tabela.length-1)
        {
           if (Character.isLetter(tabela[i]))
           {
            crke++;
            i++;
           }
            if (Character.isDigit(tabela[i]))
            {
                stevilke++;
                i++;
            }
            if (Character.isWhitespace(tabela[i]))
            {
                presledki++;
                i++;
            }
        }  
       System.out.println(String.format("V besedilu je %d %s ", crke,crke==2,crke >2 ? "crka":"crki":"crke"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't link to code; include the *relevant* portions in the question itself.

Comment: Please, post your code directly in the question. Very few people will bother to follow off-site links, and in many cases these links stop working and render this question useless in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your input. I managed to solve my problem this way.

```
package vaja13;
import java.util.*;
class Vaja13 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.print("Vnesi besedilo: ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String besedilo = sc.nextLine();
        char [] tabela  = besedilo.toCharArray();
        int crke = 0, stevke = 0, presledki = 0, i = 0;
        while(i<tabela.length)
        {
           if (Character.isLetter(tabela[i]))
           {
                crke++;
           }
           else if (Character.isDigit(tabela[i]))
            {
                stevke++;
            }
           else if (Character.isWhitespace(tabela[i]))
            {
                presledki++;
            }
           i++;
        }     


        Beseda besedaCrka = new Beseda
        (
                new String[]{"crk","crka","crki","crke"}
        );
        Beseda besedaStevka = new Beseda
        (
                new String []{"stevk","stevka","stevki","stevke"}
        );
        Beseda besedaPresledek = new Beseda 
        (
                new String [] {"presledkov","presledek","presledka","presledki"}
        );
        Beseda glagolBiti = new Beseda
        (
                new String [] {"je","je","sta","so"}
        );
        System.out.format("V besedilu %s %d %s, %d %s in %d %s.\n",
        glagolBiti.vrniObliko(crke),crke,besedaCrka.vrniObliko(crke),
        stevke,besedaStevka.vrniObliko(stevke),
        presledki,besedaPresledek.vrniObliko(presledki));

    }    
}
/**
 * Razred Beseda shranjuje slovnično obliko besede.
 */
class Beseda
{
    String oblikaBesede [];
    Beseda(String oblikaBesede[])
    {
        this.oblikaBesede = oblikaBesede;
    }
    String vrniObliko(int kolicina)
    {
      return  (kolicina < 1 || kolicina > 4? oblikaBesede[0] :
              (kolicina == 2 ? oblikaBesede[2] :
              (kolicina == 3 || kolicina == 4 ? oblikaBesede[3] :
              oblikaBesede[1])));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the last `System.out.println` line, the 3 conditions part

```
crke==2,crke >2 ? "crka":"crki":"crke"
```

is invalid Java syntax, you could use:

```
crke==2 ? "crka": crke > 2 ? "crki" :"crke"
```

This is a bit hard to read, though. Note that `? :` operator associates from right to left.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`System.out.println(String.format("V besedilu je %d %s ", crke,crke==2,crke >2 ? "crka":"crki":"crke"));`

You have to do :

`System.out.println(String.format("V besedilu je %d %s ", crke, (crke==2 ? "crka": (crke > 2? "crki": "crke"))));`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a lookup table for suffixes, and use it with a call to `Math.min`, like this:

```
private static String[] suffix = new String[] {"crka", "crki", "crke"};
...
for (int i = 0 ; i != 5 ; i++) {
    System.out.print(i+" ");
    System.out.println(String.format("V besedilu je %d %s ", i, suffix[Math.min(i, 2)]));
}
```

The core of this solution is in the expression `Math.min(i, 2)`, which evaluates as follows for non-negative values of `i`:

- `0` when `i` is `0`
- `1` when `1` is one
- `2` when `i` is `2` or above.

Note that the code above would fail for negative values of `i`.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/0CN8Fm)